# This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised

Tags: nginx, ssl

This is on Geoserver which uses Jetty/Java. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-22-04) article on a Debian machine and then added SSL with Certbot (my padlock is fine). The [message](https://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/this-connection-is-not-secure.jpg) comes up when I click the user/password input box. It seems like a mixed content warning but I don't know what Nginx or Geoserver configuration I need to change. I have v2.22.2.

```
server {

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        # root /path/to/myapp/public;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://172.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
}
```

Comment: Please share Nginx conf.

Comment: @JoelCrypto edited. It also could be that Nginx isn't serving my page since when I open the main domain, it says Powered by Eclipse Jetty:// Server.

Comment: Who is listening on port 80 and 443? Did you put https:// ?

Comment: @JoelCrypto I'm using https://. `$ ss -tupln` shows
tcp     LISTEN   0        511                      [::]:80               [::]:*, tcp     LISTEN   0        511                      [::]:443              [::]:*. Stopping Nginx removes the 80 and 443 mentions.

Comment: @JoelCrypto but ss gives no mention of Nginx or 80/443's processes. But if I stop Nginx, I can't open anything so I guess it is being used.

Comment: Please share results of OpenSSL s_client result on port 443 (certificate and OCSP response) (see man).

Comment: looks like you've gone to `http://www.donationcoder.com` rather than `https://www.donationcoder.com` - so of course the connection is insecure

Comment: @JaromandaX that's just an image I found since I can't snapshot my own screen without the message disappearing. On my actual site I see the message with https.